# how to increase the round-off limit in python?

Tags: python, floating-point, rounding

I wanted to know how to manually increase the round-0ff limit of a floating point number so that while performing power calculations, the output doesn't end up at 0.0 after a range of 0's

ex:`math.pow(0.0000000000000001223,100)`

```
0.0
```

I want the actual value of power calculation here..I wanted to perform math.log function from the output of the above calculation. But since its returning 0.0 i'm not able to perform log function. So how can i extend this round off limit value for once and for all ?? Is there any method to deal with this ??

Please help!!

expected output =

Answer (score 4):

Instead of working hard in order to represent numbers beyond your architecture's basic capabilities, you can simply reformulate your calculation in a more numeric-friendly way:

```
log(x**100) --> 100*log(x)
```

You get:

```
x = 0.9
math.log(x**100)
=> -10.536051565782628
100*math.log(x)
=> -10.536051565782628

x = 0.0000000000000001223
math.log(x**100)
=> ValueError: math domain error
100 * math.log(x)
=> -3664.0054631199696
```

Comment: No , I need to first perform math.pow(x, 100) first and then compute log value for that ..

Comment: why is the order important?

Comment: you get that error because log(x) is 0.0 after a certain interval of 0's.. I'm asking how to extend that limit

Comment: You don't get an error because `log(x**100)` is 0, you get it because `x**100` is 0, then you take `log(0)`. If what you need is to compute `log(x**100)`, I showed you how to do that. If your goal is different, please explain what it is.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use [decimals](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html):

```
>>>from decimal import Decimal
>>>Decimal(0.0000000000000001223)
>>>pow(n, 100)
Decimal('5.528988716402754783815478616E-1592')
```

Comment: How do you then take the `math.log` of that?

Comment: Exactly the same as for any other numbers :)

Comment: Then you need a different algorithm or computer ;)

Comment: @shx2: You use the `Decimal.ln` method.